# Cannot change location of build output

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

[image]

I changed it right there. However, it still show that the program runs on arbitrage2 instead of arbitrage 3.

There is a log file whose location I have no idea that says

```
=====================
3/23/2023 10:35:24 PM
Recoverable
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: The name "Output path" contains an invalid character " ".
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowArgument(Exception innerException, String resourceName, Object[] args)
```

I have no idea why the output path contain invalid character. There is no invalid character on the output path.

Comment: Is it possible you have a space after the 3?

Comment: Did you try to edit the project file by hand?  That looks like a complaint about an MSBuild property or the like.  It's complaining that the name "Output Path" is invalid because it's not allowed to have a space in it.

Comment: There is no space after the 3. Also I don't type the stuff my self. i select from a browser. I think that's how it works. So there is no way I add space after 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try opening the vbproj file to set the output directory.

[image: There must be]
[image]

Comment: I can change the output path that way but I cannot change it via visual studio interface. I can change it via notepad

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project to test if the problem is specific to your project or your Visual studio?

Comment: not yet. But I didn't used to have this problem