# Why I cannot change the build output path conveniently using IDE interface

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

This is related to question

[Cannot change location of build output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75825395/cannot-change-location-of-build-output/75830827#75830827)

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>..\arbitrage4\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>bitcoinopportunities24.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <DefineConstants>Win32=True</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>
    </NoWarn>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <WarningsAsErrors>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036</WarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Basically I can change the output directory to anything I want by just changing that texts.

However, changing the .vbproj directly is dangerous and not convenient anyway.

I prefer to change it here

[image]

But I cannot do so. The program keeps being made at arbitrage4 instead of arbitrage3.

I wonder why.

Also the first time I open the project file it's always empty. As if there is no link between the output location and the vbproj file.

What's wrong? What's going on?

Update:

When I tried to change the output path using IDE Interface I got this error code

I am sure it's related. However, the error basically says that my output path contains " ". I do not see that.

Here is what I think is going on

```
 The name "Output path" contains an invalid character " "
```

The vbproj file do not contain character output path with space. It seems that vb.net think that the name "Output path" itself contains " "

```
=====================
3/27/2023 3:08:01 PM
Recoverable
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: The name "Output path" contains an invalid character " ".
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowArgument(Exception innerException, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.XmlUtilities.VerifyThrowArgumentValidElementName(String name)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectPropertyElement.CreateDisconnected(String name, ProjectRootElement containingProject)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.ProjectPropertyWriter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<SetPropertyValueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__131.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__131.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.ProjectPropertyWriter.<SetPropertyValueAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.ProjectProperties.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<SetPropertyValueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__130`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__130`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.ProjectPropertiesBase.<>c__DisplayClass33_0.<<Microsoft-VisualStudio-ProjectSystem-Properties-IProjectProperties-SetPropertyValueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__129.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__129.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.InterceptedProjectProperties.<SetPropertyValueAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.PropertyPages.PageProperty.<SetValueAtDataSourceAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.ProjectSetUIPropertyValueActionCore.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.ProjectSetUIPropertyValueActionBase`1.<ReceiveResultAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.QueryDataProviders.ProjectUpdateBatchProvider.ProjectUpdateBatchExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<ExecuteActionsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__129.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__129.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.QueryDataProviders.ProjectUpdateBatchProvider.ProjectUpdateBatchExecutor.<ExecuteActionsAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.QueryBatchExecutorBase.<OnRequestProcessFinishedAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.QueryUpdateExecutionManager.<OnRequestProcessFinishedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.ExecutableQueryDataProducer`2.InnerResultReceiver.<Microsoft-VisualStudio-ProjectSystem-Query-Execution-IQueryResultReceiver<TResult>-OnRequestProcessFinishedAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.QueryDataProviders.ProjectQueryDataProvider.ProjectByIdDataProducer.<SendRequestAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.MergedQueryByIdDataProducer.ProcessManager.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.ExecutableQueryDataProducer`2.<ExecuteAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.QueryServerExecutionEngine.<RunDataProducerAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.QueryServerExecutionEngine.<ExecuteExecutableAsync>d__11`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.PropertyContext.<>c__DisplayClass42_0.<<SetUnevaluatedValue>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentException: The name "Output path" contains an invalid character " ".
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowArgument(Exception innerException, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.XmlUtilities.VerifyThrowArgumentValidElementName(String name)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectPropertyElement.CreateDisconnected(String name, ProjectRootElement containingProject)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.ProjectPropertyWriter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<SetPropertyValueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__131.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__131.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.ProjectPropertyWriter.<SetPropertyValueAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.ProjectProperties.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<SetPropertyValueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__130`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__130`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.ProjectPropertiesBase.<>c__DisplayClass33_0.<<Microsoft-VisualStudio-ProjectSystem-Properties-IProjectProperties-SetPropertyValueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__129.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__129.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.InterceptedProjectProperties.<SetPropertyValueAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.PropertyPages.PageProperty.<SetValueAtDataSourceAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.ProjectSetUIPropertyValueActionCore.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.ProjectSetUIPropertyValueActionBase`1.<ReceiveResultAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.QueryDataProviders.ProjectUpdateBatchProvider.ProjectUpdateBatchExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<ExecuteActionsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__129.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.<ExecuteWithinLockAsync>d__129.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.QueryDataProviders.ProjectUpdateBatchProvider.ProjectUpdateBatchExecutor.<ExecuteActionsAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.QueryBatchExecutorBase.<OnRequestProcessFinishedAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.QueryUpdateExecutionManager.<OnRequestProcessFinishedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.ExecutableQueryDataProducer`2.InnerResultReceiver.<Microsoft-VisualStudio-ProjectSystem-Query-Execution-IQueryResultReceiver<TResult>-OnRequestProcessFinishedAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.QueryDataProviders.ProjectQueryDataProvider.ProjectByIdDataProducer.<SendRequestAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.MergedQueryByIdDataProducer.ProcessManager.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.ExecutableQueryDataProducer`2.<ExecuteAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.QueryServerExecutionEngine.<RunDataProducerAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.Execution.QueryServerExecutionEngine.<ExecuteExecutableAsync>d__11`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.PropertyContext.<>c__DisplayClass42_0.<<SetUnevaluatedValue>b__0>d.MoveNext()<---

===================
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right configuration? Maybe you've set the value against the release configuration and not any other configuration? See in Build - Confiiguration Manager and switch between active configurations.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project to test if the problem is specific to your project or your Visual studio?

Comment: @JiachenLi-MSFT as far as I remember, this project didn't have this problem either. It used to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try unload project.

[image]

And then reload project

[image]